# MariaDB Trigger joining two tables?

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

If you have two tables (course and teacher)

- table course contains: C#,  course_name,   teacher,   supervisor
- table teacher contains:T#,  teacher_name,  department

Teacher and supervisor are foreign keys meaning they contain T#.

Now i want to make a trigger that checks if teacher and supervisor are both from the same department (mathematics, programming etc.),  if not then an error should show. It should be an "insert" of a new course trigger.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: phpmyadmin version 4.6.6deb5

Comment: What do you have so far? Something like `(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT department) FROM teacher WHERE T# IN (NEW.teacher, NEW.supervisor)) <> 1)` should work as a check within the trigger.

Comment: This is your phpmyadmin version. To see your MySQL version, you can run `select version()`

Comment: oh it said version: 10.4.11

Comment: That's a MariaDB version, not a MySQL version. I've updated the question's tags.

Comment: You are reaching into "that does not belong in the db" areas.  Business logic should be in the application layer.  The database is a "repository" and the "source of truth".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following trigger:

```
delimiter //
create trigger trg_ins_course_teacher_supervisor 
before insert on course
for each row
begin
    if 
        (select t.department from teacher t where t.t# = new.teacher)
        != (select t.department from teacher t where t.t# = new.supervisor)
    then
        signal 
            sqlstate '45000' 
            set message_text = 'teacher and supervisor must belong to the same department';
    end if;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: OP is looking to determine if the departments of the teacher and supervisor are the same, not whether the teacher and supervisor are.

Comment: @Uueerdo: ah, my bad... Thanks.

Comment: @Uueerdo: I (think I) fixed this.

Comment: yeah Uueerdo is right, im looking to make sure the department of both teacher and supervisor is the same

Comment: @Yulaw16: yes. That's what the trigger does now.

Comment: Yes this worked!! thank you so much, I was stuck for 2 days before signing up here :D

Comment: @GMB yep, that would have been my other suggestion for the condition to check.